# How to configure Host Distribution Rule for File Shares in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, crawling, enterprise-search

Normally when we create a new Host Distribution Rule it asks for Hostname and Crawl db name. But my requirement is to configure this for File Shares.
I cannot find any article to configure Host Distribution for File Shares in SharePoint 2010.

Please guide me to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the hostname of the fileshare, e.g. \\**servername**\fileshare => enter **servername** in the Host Distribution Rule and everything from this fileshare should be stored in the specified crawl DB.

TBH I have not verified it, but the **Add Host Rule** page has some indicators:

- Enter the hostname affected by this rule *without including the protocol.* (No protocol means its not limited to sharepoint content)
- Examples: myintranetsite; server:80; *server.dns.company.com* (not as you would typically name a sharepoint instance)

Comment: I am unable to enter hostname as \\servername\fileshare. It is giving:                                                     "This is not a valid host name. Enter a valid host name to create a distribution rule. Examples of invalid host names are: http://intranetsite; server/sites/site1; Examples of valid host names are: intranetsite; intranetsite.dns.company.com; intranetsite:8888"

Comment: Have you tried it with the hostname only?

Comment: I am able to add host name for particular site but not able to configure it for file share e.g. \\spserver1\file1. Here \\spserver1\file1 is shared location on my machine.